# Syntax error near variable, expected a step expression in loop for (XQuery, SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

```
DECLARE @x xml = 
'<A>
    <B name="235">
        <A1>
            <C id="1.1"/>
            <D id="1.2" />
        </A1>
    </B>
    <B name="535">
        <A1>
            <C id="2.1"/>
            <D id="2.2" />
        </A1>
    </B>   
</A>'
```

I want to get attribute value of ancestor B (idB) for each tag on 4 level (C, D).

For example:

```
<node tag="C">
  <id>1.1</id>
  <idB>235</idB>
</node>
<node tag="D">
  <id>1.2</id>
  <idB>235</idB>
</node>
<node tag="C">
  <id>2.1</id>
  <idB>535</idB>
</node>
<node tag="D">
  <id>2.2</id>
  <idB>535</idB>
</node>
```

I use XQuery in SQL Server:

```
SELECT @x.query('for $b in /A/B/A1/*
                 return
                    <node tag="{local-name($b)}">   
                        <id>{data($b/@*[1])}</id>
                        <idB>{data(//logu[.//$b]/@*[1])}</idB>
                    </node>
        ')
```

But I get an error;

> Syntax error near "$b", expected a step expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following XQuery.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @x xml = 
N'<A>
    <B name="235">
        <A1>
            <C id="1.1"/>
            <D id="1.2" />
        </A1>
    </B>
    <B name="535">
        <A1>
            <C id="2.1"/>
            <D id="2.2" />
        </A1>
    </B>   
</A>';

SELECT @x.query('
    for $b in /A/B/A1/*
    return <node tag="{local-name($b)}">   
            <id>{data($b/@*[1])}</id>
            <idB>{data($b/../../@name)}</idB>
        </node>
');
```

> Output

```
<node tag="C">
  <id>1.1</id>
  <idB>235</idB>
</node>
<node tag="D">
  <id>1.2</id>
  <idB>235</idB>
</node>
<node tag="C">
  <id>2.1</id>
  <idB>535</idB>
</node>
<node tag="D">
  <id>2.2</id>
  <idB>535</idB>
</node>
```